# Why does Dart complain about null safety in one function but not the other - functions are the same?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code executes perfectly:

```
  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
```

This code, however, does not. Error is: *The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned...*

```
  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() {
    _NewTransactionState();
  }
```

Why? Isn't this just two alternative ways of writing the same thing?

(Latest Android Studio if that is important).

Comment: `=>` is a shortcut in Dart for defining a method which executes one statement and returns the value from that execution. So the two methods is not equal since you are missing a `return` in your second method.

Comment: Thanks. So there is an implied return.

Answer (score 3):

The second function is missing a `return` statement.

```
  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() {
   return _NewTransactionState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one must return the state like this:

```dart
  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() {
    return _NewTransactionState();
  }
```